# Diamond-Symbol at the end of an environment

Tags: environments, theorems

I want that theorems, lemmas, examples... are ended with a diamond. Like this:[image]

I found out that I can use \hfill\mbox{$\diamond$}.
But I already wrote my document with 100s of examples, lemmas... I don't want to set it manually. So I thought I could set it up in \theoremstyle.
Where do I have to set this? Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=15, BCOR = 10mm,parskip=half-, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheoremstyle{definition}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{:}{5 pt}{}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}[]{Definition}

\begin{document}
      Here's the example.

\begin{defi}
       Does the diamond appear?
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. which document class are you using, your code doesn't compile as it is missing that

Comment: @JamestT I use scrartcl. Sorry, I added it.

Comment: If you use `ntheorem` instead og `amsthm` then this is a feature of this package. Note that the method for styling in `ntheorem` is different.

Comment: @daleif I had to redefine all my environments then. Hm, if there is no other possibility, I think I have to do it

Comment: Why? `ntheorem` also uses `\newtheorem`  it is just the interface for setting the look of the theorem that is different. `\theoremstyle` means something differently in `ntheorem`. Additionaly, apart from a few styles that needs to be set for each env definition, the `\newtheorem` just saves the current value of the settings. So if all your theorems need to have italic body you only need to set is once.

Comment: @daleif I'm a total noob in latex. If I do so, I get 3450134 error messages. And I found out that I cannot load amsthm and ntheorem together. That means I have to define my own proof environment. But I don't even know how to do that, so this is unfortunaltey no option.

Comment: All packages has manuals... And the proof env is just an theorem with no number, and there is a style for that.

Comment: [Crosspost](https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?p=121176#p121176) (in German).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\AtEndEnvironment` to automatically add your code (or my slightly adapted version) every time your `defi` environment ends.

As I use not only `\diamond`s at the end of some environments but also `\triangle`, I personally want them to have (approximately) the same size, so I added an environment `defiBig` which adds a rescaled `\diamond`. This resizing involves the `scalerel` package.
[image: Result]

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=15, BCOR = 10mm,parskip=half-, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel} % only necessary for the version with big \diamond

\newtheoremstyle{definition}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{:}{5 pt}{}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}[]{Definition}
\AtEndEnvironment{defi}{\null\hfill\ensuremath{\diamond}}
% For a bigger \diamond you can use the following:
\newtheorem{defiBig}[defi]{DefinitionBig}
\newlength\myheight  \settoheight\myheight{$\triangle$}
\AtEndEnvironment{defiBig}{\null\hfill\ensuremath{\scaleto{\diamond}{\myheight}}}

\begin{document}
      Here's the example.
      \begin{defi}
             Does the diamond appear?
      \end{defi}
      \begin{defiBig}
             Does the big diamond appear?
      \end{defiBig}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @mathquester exactly which LaTeX installation are you using? Seems very old

Comment: Note that this construction is fragile. One may end up in a situation where the diamond is on a line of its own at the top of the next page.

Comment: As Celdor and daleif said, you seem to have not updated your stuff for a while. For me it works in Overleaf, probably you need to add `\usepackage{etoolbox}` to your preamble.

Comment: @daleif It's from 2017 and I'm too unexperienced to update it. I won't do it before my thesis is finished because else everything will be broken. But it works now, thank you!

Comment: @Οὖτις It's fine, thank you. One more question: What do I do if the environment ends with a \[ \] environment? The diamond then shpuld be on the line, but it makes a line break here.

Comment: @daleif Just out of curiosity: Is there a way to overcome this? Maybe by adding `\nobreak` like in Celdor's answer? Or let me say it in other words: Why does Celdor's version not have this drawback?

Comment: @mathquester You mean with an equation like `\[ ... \]`? This is probably not easy to resolve, you have the same problem with `proof`s: they will add the qed-symbol on a new line if the environment ends with e.g. an equation, an (itemize/enumerate) list or similar

Comment: @Οὖτις `ntheorem` can add the marker into some math constructions....

Comment: @Οὖτις Yes, that't what I mean. In a proof I can say \qedhere and it works fine. But in an environment? Well you could say "Take a proof environment as as blueprint and define it as your theorem-environment". But I am really bad at all this. So, what I have now is fine for me. I will redefine the cases, where a theorem ends with an equation or something similar and brute-force-code this

Comment: As far as I know it will always be vulnerable when added at the end like that. My example was your code and then having `\[....\]` at the end of the env and then adding space before the end.

Comment: @Οὖτις Actually I don't want to use ntheorem, because it does not work with my already defined environments and I am too bad at defining this all new.

Comment: Note that several packages offer `\mdlgwhtdiamond `, `\mdlgwhtlozenge `, and `\diamondsuit` as alternatives for the larger diamond symbol.

Answer (score 5):

Just to be consistent, here is a solution using `ntheorem`. It has not changed in like 10 years should should not have issues with a 2017 installation. Just remember it takes several compilations for the markers to settle.

Caveat: The `ntheorem` envs with markers does not like blank lines before the `\end{env}` part.

Code example including how to define `proof`:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=15, BCOR = 10mm,parskip=half-, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremsymbol{\enskip\ensuremath{\diamond}}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

% body font is shared from above
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theoremsymbol{\enskip\ensuremath{\Box}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}


\begin{document}
Here's the example.

\begin{defi}
  Does the diamond appear?
\end{defi}

\begin{proof}
  Test
\end{proof}
     
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A more elegant way is as follows. **By the way, it's better to select the ending symbol as the same as the qed symbol.** Just as what I said about theorem formats in my book, the qed symbol indicates "the ending of a proof". So we can generally use the symbol to indicate “the transitory ending of some texts" and extend its use rang to all kinds of propositions, definitions, remarks and so on without proofs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}%for \Diamond
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\Diamond$}

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{thm}{\pushQED{\qed}\theorem}{\popQED\endtheorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newenvironment{defi}{\pushQED{\qed}\definition}{\popQED\enddefinition}

\begin{document}

Here are the examples.

\begin{theorem}
Does the diamond appear? No!
\end{theorem}

\begin{thm}
Does the diamond appear? Yes!
\end{thm}

\begin{definition}
Does the diamond appear? No!
\end{definition}

\begin{defi}
Does the diamond appear? Yes!
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following image shows how I use the qed symbol personally.

[image]

Comment: And now you just gave proofs a diamond marker.

Comment: @daleif In fact, I usually use the square at the end of propositions without proofs. Since both the symbols at the end of propositions without proofs and the end of proofs means "the ending", so it's better to set them to be the same.

Comment: I have several lecturers who would disagree and feel it very confusing to the reader.

Comment: @daleif So it may be necessary to say it clearly at the first time just like when to use it at the end of proofs at the first time.

Comment: If you will put the `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\Diamond$}` at the begin definition of the `defi` environment the change won't be applied to proofs, but only to definitions

Comment: @UdiFogiel Yes. You mean put `\renewcommand...` before `\pushQED`.

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 3):

You could create a wrapper environment which would add a diamond at the end of the environment defined by `amsthm`. Something around these lines:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=15, BCOR = 10mm,parskip=half-, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheoremstyle{definition}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{:}{5 pt}{}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ddefi}[]{Definition}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{defi}{s +b}{%
  \begin{ddefi}
    #2\nolinebreak\IfBooleanT{#1}{\hfill}\enspace$\diamond$
  \end{ddefi}}{}


\begin{document}
Here's the example.
\begin{defi}
  Does the diamond appear
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}*
  Does the diamond appear
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT. The code based on standard `\newenvironment`:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=15, BCOR = 10mm,parskip=half-, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheoremstyle{definition}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{:}{5 pt}{}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ddefi}[]{Definition}
\newenvironment{defi}{\begin{ddefi}}{\nolinebreak\hfill\enspace$\diamond$\end{ddefi}}


\begin{document}
Here's the example.
\begin{defi}
  Does the diamond appear
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get Undefined control sequence. \NewDocumentEnvironment

Comment: `\NewDocumentEnvironment` is defined in `xparse` but since the October 2020 (I think) it is a part of the kernel. I guess you run an old LaTeX distribution, which you really should update. For the time being, add `\usepackage{xparse}`.

Comment: Now I get LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type" Unknown argument type 'b' for the command '\environment defi'. For immediate help type H <return>.

Comment: @mathquester please update your question with information about your LaTeX installation. The version numbers is listed at the top of the log file.

Comment: @mathquester see my update and try to compile the new code. I checked it runs on TeXLive 2014.